# LINQ to SQL - Using TransactionScope for SELECT statement - is call to Complete() necessary?

Tags: sql, linq, transactionscope

I'm using a LINQ to SQL class to define a query, and then calling the ToList() method, which executes the query. The ToList() call is wrapped in a 'using TransactionScope' block to achieve the 'NOLOCK' hint. The query is read-only, so I'm not sure if the call to TransactionScope.Complete() is necessary in this case. Here is the example I followed, which does not make this call: [Getting LINQ to SQL and Entities to use NOLOCK](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking no.  Complete() in C# is the same as calling Commit in SQL, but since this is a select statement there is nothing to commit.  Any other residual constructs resulting from the TransactionScope will be disposed of at the end of the using { } block so I don't think Complete() is necessary in your case.

Comment: That's the confirmation I was looking for. Thank you